# How to consume Kafka messages with a protobuf definition in Apache Beam?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-beam, apache-beam-io, protobuf-java, apache-beam-kafkaio

I'm using KafkaIO unbounded source in a Apache Beam pipeline running on DataFlow. Following configuration works for me

```
Map<String, Object> kafkaConsumerConfig  = new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
  put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
  put("group.id", "my.group.id");
}};

p.apply(KafkaIO.<String, String>read()
        .withBootstrapServers("ip1:9092,ip2:9092,ip3:9092")
        .withConsumerConfigUpdates(kafkaConsumerConfig)
        .withTopic("my.topic")
        .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
        .withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
        .withMaxNumRecords(10)
        .withoutMetadata())
// do something
```

Now as I have a protobuf definition for the messages in my topic I would like to use it to convert the kafka records in Java objects.

Following configuration doesn't work and requires a Coder:

```
 p.apply(KafkaIO.<String, Bytes>read()
        .withBootstrapServers("ip1:9092,ip2:9092,ip3:9092")
        .withConsumerConfigUpdates(kafkaConsumerConfig)
        .withTopic("my.topic")
        .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
        .withValueDeserializer(BytesDeserializer.class)
        .withMaxNumRecords(10)
        .withoutMetadata())
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find out what is the right Value Deserializer + Coder combination and cannot find similar examples in the documentation. Do you have any working examples for using Protobuf with Kafka source in Apache Beam?

Comment: have you found a workaround for this issue? have you got a working example?
@Ira Re

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deserialise protobuf messages, you need a custom class which implements the `Deserializer` interface from the apache kafka library. This deserialisation is the same for other models too, not only apache beam.

To get the apache kafka library you can add `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients` as a dependency.

Then create the custom deserializer class, which would look something like:

```java
public class ProtoDeserializer implements Deserializer<YourProtoClass> {
    @Override
    public YourProtoClass deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        if (data == null) return null;

        try {
            return YourProtoClass.parseFrom(data);
        } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use that class in you pipeline:

```java
 p.apply(KafkaIO.<String, Bytes>read()
        .withBootstrapServers("ip1:9092,ip2:9092,ip3:9092")
        .withConsumerConfigUpdates(kafkaConsumerConfig)
        .withTopic("my.topic")
        .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
        .withValueDeserializer(ProtoDeserializer.class)
        .withMaxNumRecords(10)
        .withoutMetadata())
```